# When profiling in Release build mode, is the generated code really Release-build-mode-optimized?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, profiling

I'm wondering: When .Net generated stack traces in a Release build when throwing exceptions, the line numbers are often off, also some stack frames that should exist when analyzing the source code are not even printed because they - presumably - got optimized away.

So when Visual Studio says a lot of time was spent in method X when CPU sampling a release build, can this be trusted or could it also be off due to optimizations?

Comment: What results are you asking about, and why are you expecting them to be inaccurate?

Comment: I think you can be sure that Visual Studio's profiling takes into account compiler optimizations. Do you have an actual question about this?

Comment: I think this calls for linking the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ Basically getting high reliabiltiy benchmarks in a JiT-compiled, Garbage Colleected runtime is hard.

Answer (score 0):

The profiler doesn't care whether you build the code in Release or Debug mode. Whatever code gets emitted it will profile it. The main goal of profiling is to measure various performance-related metrics and locate bottlenecks. So the profiler is designed to be minimally intrusive to be able to make sufficiently accurate measurements. Typically, you'd profile optimized code because that's the code that gets used on production systems.

Regarding stack traces, the reasons that some stack frames might be missing is typically because of method inlining, an important optimization performed by the JIT compiler. So if A calls B, which in turn calls C and if the JIT compiler inlined B into A, then the call stack will show you that A called C and there will be no frame for B even though it's there in the source code. Also some stack frames might be missing because the profiler had no sufficient debugging information on them so it could not walk the stack fully. Similarly, source code line numbers may not match because the JIT compiler may rearrange the code or remove some pieces of code, making it difficult to have an accurate mapping between native code and source code. So you'll end up seeing an approximate mapping.

Comment: That may all be so, but how does this answer my question?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky You asked "So when Visual Studio says a lot of time was spent in method X when CPU sampling a release build, can this be trusted or could it also be off due to optimizations?" My answer says "yes it can be trusted irrespective of whether optimizations are enabled, whatever code gets emitted will be profiled." Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I would like to understand why I should trust the profiler, when I can't trust the stack traces. CPU sampling is also gathering stack traces, so why could the profiler do very often (many many times every second), what is not possible when throwing an exception - a normally rare thing where it would be ok (and helpful) to spend some more time figuring out the true stack trace. OT: Thumbs up to the Syria videos in your profile.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky I've edited my answer to address the first part of your question.